# Identificar que tema está en uso: el navegador o el del usuario

Tags: javascript, local-storage, theme, prefers-color-scheme

Quisiera poder escribir en un div cuál tema está en uso actualmente con Javascript:

Si el modo oscuro o claro es por primera vez, entonces sería el del navegador o el del teléfono.

O sino, el cambio del usuario con un botón.

Esto es lo quiero lograr

```
const sistemaNegro = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
const sistemaClaro = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)");

if(sistemaClaro.matches) {
  nombreTema.textContent = "Sistema claro"
} else if(sistemaNegro.matches) {
  nombreTema.textContent = "Sistema oscuro"
}
```

Y esto es mi codigo para el cambio del usuario

```
window.setUserTheme = function(newTheme) {
 
 document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-tema", newTheme);
 localStorage.setItem("theme", newTheme);

  if(newTheme == "oscuro") {
    nombreTema.textContent = "Mi tema oscuro"
  } else if(newTheme == "claro") {
    nombreTema.textContent = "Mi tema claro"
  }

};
```

Estos dos códigos quisiera unificar en una sola función, pero no sé dónde ubicar.

Mi codigo completo:

```js
const userTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
const sistemaNegro = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
const sistemaClaro = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)");
const nombreTema = document.getElementById("nombreTema");
const botonOscuro = document.getElementById("modoOscuro");
const botonClaro = document.getElementById("modoClaro");


if(userTheme === "dark" || (!userTheme && sistemaNegro.matches)) {
  setTheme("dark");
}

sistemaNegro.addEventListener("change", function (e) {

  if(!localStorage.getItem("theme")) {
    setTheme(e.matches ? "dark" : "light");
  }

});

function setTheme(newTheme) {
 
document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-tema", newTheme);
};

// SIN FUNCIONAR CORRECTAMENTE
/*
if(sistemaClaro.matches) {
  nombreTema.textContent = "Sistema claro"
} else if(sistemaNegro.matches) {
  nombreTema.textContent = "Sistema oscuro"
}
*/

window.setUserTheme = function (newTheme) {
 
 document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-tema", newTheme);
 localStorage.setItem("theme", newTheme);

 if(newTheme == "oscuro") {
  nombreTema.innerHTML = `
    <div class="titulo">Mi tema oscuro <span class="bi-moon-fill"></span></div
    <div class="subtitulo textoPeque">Seleccionaste el modo oscuro. Éste sera por defecto ahora</div>
  `;
 } else if(newTheme == "claro") {
  nombreTema.innerHTML = `
    <div class="titulo">Mi tema claro <span class="bi-sun-fill"></span></div>
    <div class="subtitulo textoPeque">Seleccionaste el modo claro. Sera por defecto ahora</div>
  `;
 }
            
};

function modoOscuro() {
  setUserTheme("oscuro");
};

function modoClaro() {
  setUserTheme("claro");
};

botonOscuro.addEventListener("click", modoOscuro);
botonClaro.addEventListener("click", modoClaro);
```

```css
:root[data-tema="oscuro"] {
  --body: #000
}

:root[data-tema="claro"] {
  --body: #fff
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body)
}
```

```html
<html data-tema="claro">
<body>

<div id="nombreTema">Activar temas</div>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark modoOscuro bi-moon-fill" id="modoOscuro">Oscuro</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-light modoClaro bi-sun-fill" id="modoClaro">Claro</button>

</body>
</html>
```